# How can I change where ASP.NET Core looks for ViewComponents?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to arrange my components folders in a way that makes sense to me. Problem is once I do, the components are not being found by ASP.NET. They can only be found when I put them in Shared/Components or Views/{NameOfView}/Components. Is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 2):

Although the official document doesn't provide a description on how to custom the location of view components, you still can follow those tutorials about how to do that with plain View files.

In short :

1. You need to custom [`RazorViewEngineOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorviewengineoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.1) options to tell Razor where your view files locate
2. In addition, you need create a `Components/YourViewComponentName/` folder to tell Razor that's where your view components locate.

**How to in details**

Suppose you want to create a view component that would render different view files of different themes :

```
public class MyViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync( string template, string theme)
    {
        template = string.IsNullOrEmpty(template) ? "Default": template; 
        theme = string.IsNullOrEmpty(theme) ? "" : "." +theme;
        return View(template+theme);
    }
}
```

You could put this file anywhere as you like. For a testing purpose, I create a folder as below :

```
Your project folder/
    App.csproj
    MyLocations/
        MyViewComponent.cs                     # MyViewComponent class 
        DefaultTheme/
            Components/                        # The name of `Components` here matters
                My/                            # Your ViewComponentName
                    Default.cshtml             # view file of your view component
                    Another.cshtml             # view file of your view component
        Theme2/
            Components/                        # The name of `Components` here matters
                My/                            # Your ViewComponentName
                    Default.Theme2.cshtml      # view file of your view component
                    Another.Theme2.cshtml      # view file of your view component
    Views/
    Controllers/
```

Note the folder name `My` should keep consistent with the view component name. If you custom the name to be `Our`, the folder name should be changed also.

To make it work, simply add a configuration for `RazorViewEngineOptions`:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>{
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("MyLocations/DefaultTheme/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("MyLocations/Theme2/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
});
```

That's all.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the components and the views anywhere you like.

E.g.

I create a folder in `Views` called `Info`

Then I create a view called `Tested.cshtml` in that folder

So in my main project directory I have:

```
ProjectName > Views > Info > Tested.cshtml
```

I then created a folder called `ViewComponents` in my main project directory.

And in that folder I created a class - the name doesn't need to end in `ViewComponent` as long as it inherits `ViewComponent` and has `IViewComponentResult Invoke()`

I suffix my ViewComponents with `VC` just for some clarity across the project.

So now I also have:

```
ProjectName > ViewComponents > TestingVC.cs
```

In the `Invoke` method in that class, I point it directly to the `ViewComponent` location I just created, making sure I use `~` to get to the main project root.

```
public class TestingVC : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Info/Tested.cshtml");
    }
}
```

Then you just invoke the ViewComponent class wherever in another view, using `nameof` to avoid magic strings:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync(nameof(ProjectName.ViewComponents.TestingVC))
```

Simples!

THere is probably a way of getting the directory of the `cshtml` file without using magic strings as well but at least this demos you can basically put the `ViewComponents` and `Views` anywhere you like.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft [Documentaiton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2#view-search-path):

> The runtime searches for the View component's view in the following paths:
>
> `/Pages/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}`
>
> `/Views/{Controller Name}/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}`
>
> `/Views/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}`
>
> The default view name for a view component is `Default`, which means your view file will typically be named `Default.cshtml`. You can specify a different view name when creating the view component result or when calling the View method.
>
> We recommend you name the view file `Default.cshtml` and use the `Views/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}` path.

Although runtime can searches in the above three paths but Microsoft suggestion is to use the following path among the three:

```
/Views/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}
```

And it makes sense! Because `ViewComponent` actually is the shared piece of view which can be used used in any where in the application from Layout page to any individual page. So by characteristics, it should always be placed inside the Shared folder.

Thank you.